# Jetty And Netty integration

Tags: java, webserver, jetty, netty

I want to build a nio based java web server. Jetty is light weighted java server and Netty is an asynchronous event-driven network application nio framework. can any one help me to integrate this two?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could build up your own webserver by using only netty.

See the examples for this:
http://docs.jboss.org/netty/3.2/xref/org/jboss/netty/example/http/

Comment: You can try this netty-jersey integration: https://github.com/kpavlov/netty-jaxrs

Answer (score 1):

**Finagle**, you can easily, and within minutes, spin up a Netty based web server using Finagle. Finagle is an open source project by Twitter.